# Creating a "Drop-Up" menu

Tags: jquery, menu

Anyone knows a jQuery menu plugin that allows that the render of menu is drop-up instead of drop-down?

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked on [Doctype](http://doctype.com/), you should probably take a look: http://doctype.com/make-jquery-mega-menu-drop-up